# Precompiled Header and MSBuild

Tags: c++, msbuild, include, precompiled-headers, stdafx.h

I have a precompiled header that needs to be included atop each .cpp in my project. I fear that I will waste a lot of time explaining and fixing that in coworkers code.

Is there an MSBuild step that I can do to `#include "stdafx.h"` at the top of all my .cpp files so it dosen't need to do done manually?

Comment: I'm confused--why do the pch requirements of your project need to affect what other people do with their projects?

Comment: @dlf Ugh, now that I reread that "other people's projects" makes no sense. I've changed it to say "coworkers code".

Comment: @JonathanMee That does make more sense. :) But if I recall correctly, if you have precompiled headers switched on, MSBuild gives you an actual build-time error if you neglect to #include stdafx.h in any cpp (unless that cpp specifically has precompiled headers disabled), which (hopefully!) makes it difficult to forget. But to answer your question directly--I'm not aware of any way to make the compiler forcibly include a particular header in every cpp whether it asks for it or not.

Comment: @Jarod42 `/Yu` is the switch that I use to indicate that _I am_ using a precompiled header, but then I need to go `#include "stdafx.h"` at the top of all the .cpps. I want to remove the need to add `#include "stdafx.h"` at the top of all my .cpps; that is to say I want to do that programatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the compiler option [/FI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx) *pathname*

which virtually *add* `#include "pathname"` at the first line of the file.

Note: the equivalent for gcc is `-include path`.

Comment: Yeah I just found it thanks I just found that /FI option thanks to your "gcc -include" comment and this page: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-February/035208.html Testing it out and then I will accept.